# Changing input radio into large div boxes

Tags: css, input, radio-button, stylesheet

I'm trying to figure out how to hide the radio buttons and instead, use div boxes so users can click on a large box instead of a small button.

Is this possible?

Comment: Check this http://viralpatel.net/blogs/css-radio-button-checkbox-background/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI provides a `buttonset` feature that may work:

```
<div id="radio"  align="center" >
<input type="radio" name ="gender" id="male" value="MALE" checked="checked"/><label for="male">MALE</label>
            <input type="radio" name ="gender" id="female" value="FEMALE" /><label for="female">FEMALE</label>
</div>
```

and script

```
$(function() {
        $( "#radio" ).buttonset();
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hardikbhalani89/ALSRj/)

Comment: Edited your answer so that it's clear you're referring to jQuery UI, which additional to jQuery.

Comment: is the jQuery UI supposed to automatically set classes associated to radio buttons? I tested it out just by copy and pasting it into my project, but its not converting the radio input to buttons? I also have jQuery UI files in my project

Comment: yes it will set automatically classes for radio...make sure you follow correct nomenclature while assigning ID and label values..as shown in Demo fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Associate `div`s with a radio button via click and you're set.

```
<div class="radio-wrap"><input type="radio"></div>


$('div.radio-wrap').click(function(e){
  $(this).find('[type=radio]').attr('checked',true);
});
```

You can hide the radio input with css or move it where you want.